# error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory (possible SAGE/python issue)

Tags: python, gcc

I see that there are a number of topics on this error message, but I've tried every solution I have found to no avail. This is my first question here, but I'm going to try and include all of the info that has been useful in other threads.

I'm attempting to install the [flagmatic](http://www.flagmatic.org) software, which is a mathematical package that works with SAGE and python. However, I'm having a compiler issue. Namely when I run

```
sage -python setup.py install
```

I receive the output:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
skipping 'flagmatic/flag.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'flagmatic.flag' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/lib/sagemath/local/include -I/usr/lib/sagemath/local/include/csage -I/usr/lib/sagemath/devel/sage/sage/ext -I/usr/lib/sagemath/devel/sage -I/usr/lib/sagemath/local/include/python2.7 -c flagmatic/flag.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/flagmatic/flag.o -O3 -Wall -Wno-strict-prototypes
**gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1**
```

Where I've bolded the last bit for emphasis, as I believe it to be at the heart of my problem. I have reinstalled the package build-essential (sudo apt-get install build-essential) to no avail.

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

cc --version
cc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
```

It seems like the compiler gcc can't find cc1 when I run it in sage. As far as I can tell, cc1 is located:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1
```

and when do this:

```
more /etc/environment
```

I get:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib"
```

It seems like since /usr/lib ins in my path, gcc should be looking there, correct? Is there an easy way to see why execvp can't find cc1 when I try and install the aforementioned package?

Please let me know if there is anything else that would be helpful re: my system specs or versions of anything. I will update here with edits:

EDIT:

```
gcc -print-prog-name=cc1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1

apt-cache policy cpp
cpp:
Installed: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
Candidate: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
Version table:
*** 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 0
500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: IIRC gcc doesn't use $PATH to locate cc1: instead it uses built-in locations. What are the outputs of `gcc -print-prog-name=cc1` and `apt-cache policy cpp`?

Comment: `gcc -print-prog-name=cc1`

`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1`

`apt-cache policy cpp`

`cpp:
  Installed: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
  Candidate: 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6
  Version table:
 *** 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

EDITED to include the second bit of info. Will edit into the main post as well.

Comment: Hmm... so I suspect that the installation process is invoking `/usr/lib/sagemath/local/bin/gcc` instead of the system's `gcc`

Comment: How did you install sage? If you used the AIMS ppa, it looks like their sagemath-upstream-binary package doesn't include a cc1 for the packaged gcc - but the package sagemath-upstream-binary-**full** does

Comment: I compiled sage from source. Should I install from a binary instead?

Comment: Sorry I can't advise you about that, however you may find the [Environment Variables](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/source.html#environment-variables) section of the build documentation helpful - in particular the section *Some standard environment variables which are used by Sage*

Comment: Thanks! I'll  look at that (and maybe install from binary) when I get better internet access. If I get it working I'll let you know so you can post an answer.

Comment: OK good luck! Feel free to post (and accept) your own answer if you resolve it

Comment: The answer to this question lies in the simple fact that gcc/g++ is a closed install.gcc/g++ depends on nothing but the compilers version own install.
It should be easy to find the answer. What is your cc?

Answer (score 1):

> How did you install sage? If you used the AIMS ppa, it looks like their sagemath-upstream-binary package doesn't include a cc1 for the packaged gcc - but the package sagemath-upstream-binary-full does –steeldriver

This comment was key. I uninstalled my version of SAGE and used the AIMS ppa with the package sagemath-upstream-binary-full. This fixed my CC1 issue.

An addendum: If you are here because of trouble with flagmatic, I was still receiving an error message about a failed cython compilation. In the file hypergraph_flag.pyx I changed line 38 from:

```
include "cdefs.pxi"
```

to

```
#include "cdefs.pxi"
```

Just in case you happened upon this thread specifically due to a flagmatic compilation error.